# SQL Server count numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and it looks like this:

```
Num1 num2  num3
----------------
1     2     2<----- grouped numbers

1     2     3<----- another group 
1     2     3<----- same numbers so I have a value of 2 

2     4     4
2     2     3
2     4     3
3
3
4
```

I would like to know how to give groups of numbers, a number value.

Example1

1, 2, 2 are grouped horizontally

Example 2

1,2,2 this combination is shown x amount of times

1,2,2 times = 1

Example 3

1,2,3 = 2 times

2,3,3 = 4 times

This works but only on single numbers

```
select num, count(*)Times
from Numbers cross apply
     (values (F2), (F3), (F4),(F5),(F6),(F7),(F8)) v(num)
where num is not null
group by num
order by num;


This also works but same problem 

select value, count(*)
from Numbers
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (F2, F3, F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9)
) u
group by value 
ORDER BY 1;
```

The idea is to expand this to 16 columns and search all rows to find the matching
sets of numbers in each row. 
Give an output of example 3, "times" being the column name

The amount of rows=2000,columns=16

if anyone can help please post

Comment: Please post a full DDL of your table, but you're probably looking for `GROUP BY`

Comment: "something like" doesn't really do a good job of describing what you want.  What result set would you want from this data?

Comment: @Black, the table might be gigantic, what's the purpose of posting it here lmao

Comment: forgive me if I'm not doing it or saying correctly I'm very new to this

Comment: @Rainb the original version of this question that I commented on didn't show the table structure at all

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I think you want the count of each number.  You can do this by unpivoting and aggregating:

```
select num, count(*)
from t cross apply
     (values (num1), (num2), (num3)) v(num)
where num is not null
group by num
order by num;
```

Comment: this works well but I'm still unable to get "runs" for lack of a better term
 as in the number 3, 5 and 10 show up 60 times in my report example 2 the numbers 256, 700, 921 show up 6 times

Comment: @StephenWilson . . . . I would suggest that you ask another question, with a better explanation and sample data.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have rephrased the question could you please take me off hold

Comment: I'm trying to work out a model of grouping for a marketing proposal using what things customers buy together to try and promote slow moving products. the numbers I'm using are sets of numbers I grabbed just to test with.